# Type Error xxx.filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

New to JavaScript as I am taking my first class. Getting an error on an assignment for a similar code we did in class. I get this error when I run the command in the terminal. I think my first block is correct, but I can be wrong. It is probably something obvious my untrained eyes doesn't see.
Thanks

```
var prices = ['100', '125', '129', '37', '38', '75', '87', '94', '300', '301',
'305', '50', '0.30', '0.01', '0.5', '5', '15', '24', '35', '1041', '1', '17',
'21', '28', '97', '6', '10', '49', '65', '89', '6', '10', '49', '65', '89'];

//convert string to integer
var numPricesArray = prices.join();
console.log("numPricesArray: " + numPricesArray);

//filter values under 25
var cutoffPrice = numPricesArray.filter(function(num){
return num < 25;
});
console.log(cutoffPrice);
```

Comment: `.join()` returns a string, not an Array. If you wanted to convert the strings to numbers, `.join()` sure won't do it. Use `prices.map(Number).filter(...` or `prices.map(parseFloat).filter(...` instead *(assuming you didn't actually mean "integer")*.

Comment: join doesn't return an array

Comment: I see. So it is my first part. Looking now I notice that the join get rid of the array. Basically I am trying to convert the strings in the array to integers. Someone did this by joining the array. But I guess I am missing the second part.

Comment: If someone did it with `.join()`, then they either just wanted a serialized string representing an array of numbers, like `"[100, 125, 129]"` to be passed or stored elsewhere, or they were going to immediately parse it again using `eval()` or `JSON.parse()` or something, which would be silly and wasteful.

Comment: Just doing `var cutoffPrices = prices.map(Number).filter(function(num) { return num < 25; })` will do it for you.

Comment: Thanks. .map is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, calling prices.join() returns a string. Specifically, it will return the string "100,125,129" and so on. Because arrays have the method filter, and strings don't, when you try to call filter on that string, an error will be thrown.

Sources:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter